# Destructuring objects with different length

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on React with ES6 and I've got an object like this :

```
const links = {
   facebook: 'https://facebook...',
   linkedin: 'https://linkedin...',
   other: {
      TRAD_KEY1: 'https://key1...',
      TRAD_KEY2: 'https://key2...',
  },
};
```

In this example, I've only got 2 "other links", but depending from my source, I can have more,  so I'm looking for a polyvalent solution to display my links like this :

```
<a href={facebook.url}>{facebook.name}</a>
<a href={linkedin.url}>{linkedin.name}</a>
<a href={other1.url}>{other1.name}</a>
<a href={other2.url}>{other2.name}</a>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what the other links are always gonna be you can destructure them just like facebook or linkedin. But if they can vary and you have no way of knowing their names or keys you might as well map them.

You can use something like:

```
const { facebook, linkedin, other } = links;
...
<a href={facebook}>Facebook</a>
<a href={linkedin}>LinkedIn</a>
{Object.keys(other).map(otherKey => {
  const otherLink = other[otherKey];

  return <a href={otherLink}>{otherKey}</a>;
}}
```

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm stuck at getting the facebook.name or url. Because right now, If I use facebook.url I get nothing because url is not defined...

Comment: @Kaherdin I didn't pay attention to your object structure. I edited the code so you can see that since you don't have a more refined structure you must make do with what you have